# Equivalent definitions of the exterior products

Tags: abstract-algebra, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

In the Wikipedia article on [alternating multilinear forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra#Alternating_multilinear_forms), two equivalent definitions of the exterior products are given.

> **Definition 1:**
>   $$
>  \omega \wedge \eta ={\frac {(k+m)!}{k!\,m!}}\operatorname {Alt} (\omega \otimes \eta ),\tag{1}
> $$
>   where
>   $$
> \operatorname{Alt}(\omega)(x_1,\ldots,x_k)=\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_k}\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)\,\omega(x_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,x_{\sigma(k)});\tag{1.5}
> $$
>   **Definition 2:**
>   $$
> {\omega \wedge \eta(x_1,\ldots,x_{k+m})} = \sum_{\sigma \in Sh_{k,m}} \operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)\,\omega(x_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, x_{\sigma(k)}) \eta(x_{\sigma(k+1)}, \ldots, x_{\sigma(k+m)}),\tag{2}
> $$
>   where here $Sh_{k,m} ⊂ S_{k+m}$ is the subset of $(k,m)$ shuffles: permutations $σ$ of the set $\{1, 2, ..., k + m\}$ such that $σ(1) < σ(2) < ... < σ(k)$, and $σ(k + 1) < σ(k + 2) < ... < σ(k + m)$.

---

Note that (1) can be rewritten as
$$
{\omega \wedge \eta(x_1,\ldots,x_{k+m})} = \frac{1}{k!m!}\sum_{\sigma \in S_{k+m}} \operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)\,\omega(x_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, x_{\sigma(k)}) \eta(x_{\sigma(k+1)}, \ldots, x_{\sigma(k+m)})\tag{1'}
$$
Thus to show that (1) and (2) are equivalent, it suffices to show that (1') are (2) are the same. Ignoring the $\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)$ part, one can count the number ofterms in (1') and (2).

---

Here is my **question**:

> How can one show that (1') and (2) are the same?

Comment: ...by inserting the definition of $\otimes$ in equation 1, expanding out equation 1, via 1.5 and then gathering terms in a way that matches equation 1'. In particular, when you apply equation 1.5 to equation 1, you're taking Alt of a $k+m$ form, so the sum is over $S_{k+m}$, which is the same index set used in equation 1'.

Comment: @JohnHughes: I have just added the tag (1.5) to match the labels in your comment. (I was confused..)

Comment: Yeah ... I figured you could work it out. :)

Comment: OK, so I lied about the index sets being the same. But the $k,m$ shuffles *do* form a subset of the $k+m$ permutations. And if you remove the order restrictions on the shuffles, then for each order-restricted shuffle of $k,m$ items, you get $k!m!$ order-*unrestricted* shuffles (by permuting the elements of each pile), and looks like a nice correspondence that can account for a factorial or two. To be honest...I'd try this for $\omega\wedge \eta$ for a couple of 2-forms, and I'll bet that the correspondence suddenly gets really obvious. Since it's only 24 terms, it shouldn't be too tough.

Comment: I tried the case $k=1,m=2$ to see what is really going on. I might come back later with my own answer. As I see, the key point is that for any given permutation $\sigma\in S_{k+m}$, it can be written as $$\sigma=\pi^{-1}\sigma_2\pi\sigma_1\tau$$ where $\tau\in Sh_{k,m}$,  $(\pi(1),\cdots,\pi(k+m))=(k+1,\cdots,k+m,1,\cdots,k)$, and $\sigma_1\in S_k$, $\sigma_2\in S_m$. It follows that $$\hbox{sgn}(\sigma)=\hbox{sgn}(\sigma_2)\hbox{sgn}(\sigma_1)\hbox{sgn}(\tau).$$ Combining with the alternating properties of $\omega$ and $\eta$, one gets the desired results.

Answer (score 2):

**Notations**

I have used $l$ instead of $m$. Moreover, I have used $S_{(.,.)}$ instead of $Sh_{.,.}$.
I also use $v_i$ instead of $x_i$.

---

Define the equivalence relation $\sim$ on $S_{k+l}$ by setting $\sigma \sim \sigma'$ iff
$$\{\sigma(1), \ldots, \sigma(k)\} = \{\sigma'(1), \ldots, \sigma'(k)\}.$$
(Note that the equality is of sets.)
It is easily checked that $\sim$ is indeed an equivalence relation. Moreover, if $\sigma \sim \sigma',$ then we also have
$$\{\sigma(k+1), \ldots, \sigma(k+l)\} = \{\sigma'(k+1), \ldots, \sigma'(k+l)\}.$$

Let $[\sigma]$ denote the equivalence class of $\sigma.$

We make the following simple observations:

1. Each equivalence class contains the same number of elements.
2. The above number is $k!l!.$
3. Every equivalence class contains exactly one $(k, l)$ shuffle.
4. Every $(k, l)$ shuffle is contained in some equivalence class.

Now, if we show that the quantity $\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)\omega(v_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, v_{\sigma(k)})\eta(v_{\sigma(k+1)}, \ldots, v_{\sigma(k+l)})$ is the same for all $\sigma$ belonging to a fixed equivalence class, then we would be done.

That is because, we could simply choose the shuffle present in the equivalence class as the representative of the class and then $(1')$ would reduce to $(2).$ To see this better, let $\Pi_1, \ldots \Pi_r$ denote the distinct equivalence classes and let $\sigma_i \in \Pi_i$ be the shuffle in that class. Then, we have
$$S_{k+l} = \bigsqcup_{i=1}^r \Pi_i$$
and thus,
\begin{align} 
  & \dfrac{1}{k!l!}\sum_{\sigma \in S_{k+l}}\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)\omega(v_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, v_{\sigma(k)})\eta(v_{\sigma(k+1)}, \ldots, v_{\sigma(k+l)})\\
  =&\;\dfrac{1}{k!l!}\sum_{i=1}^{r}\sum_{\sigma \in \Pi_i}\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)\omega(v_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, v_{\sigma(k)})\eta(v_{\sigma(k+1)}, \ldots, v_{\sigma(k+l)})\\
  =&\;\dfrac{1}{k!l!}\sum_{i=1}^{r}\sum_{\sigma \in \Pi_i}\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma_i)\omega(v_{\sigma_i(1)}, \ldots, v_{\sigma_i(k)})\eta(v_{\sigma_i(k+1)}, \ldots, v_{\sigma_i(k+l)})\\
  &\text{note that now the inner quantity is independent of $\sigma$}\\
  =&\;\dfrac{1}{k!l!}\sum_{i=1}^{r}(k!l!)\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma_i)\omega(v_{\sigma_i(1)}, \ldots, v_{\sigma_i(k)})\eta(v_{\sigma_i(k+1)}, \ldots, v_{\sigma_i(k+l)})\\
  =&\;\sum_{\sigma \in S_{(k, l)}}\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)\omega(v_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, v_{\sigma(k)})\eta(v_{\sigma(k+1)}, \ldots, v_{\sigma(k+l)}).
\end{align}

Thus, now all we need to finish is the following claim.

---

**Claim.** If $[\sigma] = [\sigma'],$ then
\begin{align} 
\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)&\omega(v_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, v_{\sigma(k)})\eta(v_{\sigma(k+1)}, \ldots, v_{\sigma(k+l)})\\
=& \operatorname{sgn}(\sigma')\omega(v_{\sigma'(1)}, \ldots, v_{\sigma'(k)})\eta(v_{\sigma'(k+1)}, \ldots, v_{\sigma'(k+l)}).
\end{align}

The claim is pretty simple and follows closely from what was written in the comments.

*Proof.* Since $\{\sigma(1), \ldots, \sigma(k)\} = \{\sigma'(1),\ldots, \sigma'(k)\},$ we can find a permutation $\tau \in S_{k+l}$ such that
$$\tau\sigma(i) = \sigma'(i), \quad i = 1, \ldots, k$$
and $\tau$ acts as identity on $\{\sigma(k+1), \ldots, \sigma(k+l)\}.$

Similarly, we can find a permutation $\pi \in S_{k+l}$ such that
$$\pi\sigma(i) = \sigma'(i), \quad i = k+1, \ldots, k+l$$
and $\pi$ acts as identity on $\{\sigma(1), \ldots, \sigma(k)\}.$

Thus, we actually get
$$\pi\tau\sigma(i) = \sigma'(i), \quad i = 1, \ldots, k+l.$$

That is to say, $\sigma' = \pi\tau\sigma.$
In particular, we have $\operatorname{sgn}\sigma' = \operatorname{sgn}\pi\cdot\operatorname{sgn}\tau\cdot\operatorname{sgn}\sigma.$
This also gives us that
$$\operatorname{sgn}\sigma'\cdot\operatorname{sgn}\pi\cdot\operatorname{sgn}\tau = \operatorname{sgn}\sigma.$$

With that in place, we prove the claim via the following calculation.
\begin{align} 
  & \operatorname{sgn}\sigma'\cdot\omega(v_{\sigma'(1)}, \ldots, v_{\sigma'(k)})\eta(v_{\sigma'(k+1)}, \ldots, v_{\sigma'(k+l)})\\
  =&\;\operatorname{sgn}\sigma'\cdot\omega(v_{\tau\sigma(1)}, \ldots, v_{\tau\sigma(k)})\eta(v_{\pi\sigma(k+1)}, \ldots, v_{\pi\sigma(k+l)})\\
  & \text{Now, we use that $\omega$ and $\eta$ are alternating}\\
  =&\;\operatorname{sgn}\sigma'\cdot\operatorname{sgn}\tau\cdot\operatorname{sgn}\pi\cdot\omega(v_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, v_{\sigma(k)})\eta(v_{\sigma(k+1)}, \ldots, v_{\sigma(k+l)})\\
  =&\;\operatorname{sgn}\sigma\cdot\omega(v_{\sigma(1)}, \ldots, v_{\sigma(k)})\eta(v_{\sigma(k+1)}, \ldots, v_{\sigma(k+l)}) & \blacksquare
\end{align}